# MySQL converting time to string (Grafana)

Tags: mysql, grafana

I am having a little trouble showing the number of times a user is running a SW version/HW version through Grafana. The following query works correctly in MySQL Workbench but when done in Grafana, the following error is given: Invalid type for column time/time_sec, must be of type timestamp or unix timestamp, got: string 1536692387

I have tried converting time_sec into a DATETIME type through CAST and CONVERT but have had no success. Does anyone have suggestions on how to handle this? Thank you.

Here is the current query (through workbench-the variables are defined in Grafana):

```
SET @$swVersion = 'LATEST';
SET @$hwString = 'TXT';

SELECT 
    IF(COUNT(user) > 0, epochStartTime, NOW()) AS time_sec,
    COUNT(user) AS 'John Doe'
FROM
    table
WHERE
    STRCMP(user, 'Name') = 0
    AND swVersion IN (@$swVersion)
    AND hwString IN (@$hwString)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(IF(COUNT(user) > 0, epochStartTime, NOW())) AS time_sec`

in your query.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding! 

Before I added the "UNIX_TIMESTAMP" I got the string of numbers when the count was greater than 0. But after adding, the result became null and gave the same error: invalid type for column time/time_sec, must be of type timestamp or unix timestamp.

Comment: Looks like `epochStartTime` in your data is already an integer timestamp - apply UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function to NOW() only:  `IF(COUNT(user) > 0, epochStartTime, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) AS time_sec`

Comment: That worked, thank you very much! I'm assuming it's because NOW() was a different type?